# What is difference between android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2

Tags: android

Can anyone explain `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 in arrayadapter` in Android?

I know in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` are layouts that are defined by Android itself.

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` only contains one `TextView`, but `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` contains two `TextView`s.

I would like an example for `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`. How do I show two `TextView`s in a `ListView` using adapter?

My code is

```
package com.app.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ExampleListViewActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] nameArr = new String[] {"Arun", "Anil", "Ankit", "Manoj"};
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                android.R.id.text1,
                                                                nameArr);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is the following. `simple_list_item_1` contains only a `TextView`, whereas `simple_list_item_2` has two inside a subclass of `RelativeLayout`. These are both taken from Jelly Bean.

**simple_list_item_1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

**simple_list_item_2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

According to the [docs for ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references
>   a single TextView.

So by default, an `ArrayAdapter` doesn't automatically fill in multiple `TextView` instances. You can, however, override the `getView()` method and fill in the two `TextView`s that appear in `R.layout.simple_list_item_2`

Comment: Exactly what bothered me the first time i ventured into it, when i found out that many adapters don't use additional views I realized that many adapters are there just to be subclassed... :)

Comment: When I need a specific look for a list, I usually subclass `BaseAdapter` and in my implementation for `getView()`, I inflate a custom layout (or recycle the one that's passed in), and fill in things as needed.

Comment: pretty much what i said in my answer below ;) with example code.

Comment: True, just figured I would elaborate on the differences between the two layouts the OP asked about.

Answer (score 16):

I found this to be the simplest answer to your question:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

    text1.setText(person[position].getName());
    text2.setText(person[position].getAge());
    return view;
  }
};
```

If you didn't notice: the trick is to supply `android.R.id.text1` as (principally unneccessary) parameter to ArrayAdapter, otherwise the call to `super` will cause an exception.

Also, this solution does not need an `Inflater` or make use of `TwoLineListItem`, which was deprecated in API 17.

Comment: I've noticed that it doesn't seem to matter if you pass in android.R.id.text1 or .text2.  However, if I put in 0, it crashes, and the method names seem to be suggesting its measuring something for placement.  I guess I could read the source code, but this is something that should be cleared up in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Like you noticed, layout_1 has one textView and it's the default one to be used.
layout_2 has two text views - the other one used as a subtext.

but here's the trick - not all adapters make use of the subtext one ;)

I found it easier (not gonna say mandatory) to write a purpose-built custom adapter for anything and everything...

For instance, here's a custom adapter that will display a name and it's status using this simple_list_item_2

This **WILL NOT** be copy/paste code, but you'll fix it with a few tweaks...

```
 public class BuddyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Buddy>
 {

private static final String tag         = "BuddyArrayAdapter";
private Context             context;

private TextView            buddyName;
private TextView            buddyStatus;
private List<Buddy>         buddies     = new ArrayList<Buddy>();

/**
 * The default constructor which is invoked to create the buddy array
 * adapter.
 * <p>
 * The adapter is needed to 'translate' data into a viewable item / widget.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the application context
 * @param objects
 *            the backing array populated by Buddy objects to be displayed.
 * @see {@link ArrayAdapter}<T>
 */

public BuddyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Buddy> objects)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.buddies = objects;
    Collections.sort(buddies);
}

/**
 * The method used for determining how many views are in this list or in
 * other words, how many views are managed by this adapter.
 * 
 * @return the number of items this adapter controls.
 */
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.buddies.size();
}


/**
 * Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
 * 
 * @param index
 *            Position of the item whose data we want within the adapter's
 *            data set.
 * @return the Buddy object data at the specified position.
 */
@Override
public Buddy getItem(int index)
{
    if (index <= getCount())    //IndexOutOfBoundsException fix
        return this.buddies.get(index);
    return this.buddies.get(getCount() - 1);
}

/**
 * Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data
 * set. You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an XML
 * layout file. When the View is inflated, the parent View (GridView,
 * ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use
 * inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) to specify a root view and
 * to prevent attachment to the root.
 * <p>
 * This method is used to generate views to be used in the ListView. This
 * the method that defines how data will look and be represented throughout
 * the UI.
 * 
 * @param position
 *            The position of the item that is being placed / The position
 *            of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose
 *            view we want.
 *            <p>
 * @param convertView
 *            The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check
 *            that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before
 *            using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display
 *            the correct data, this method can create a new view.
 *            Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so
 *            that this View is always of the right type (see
 *            getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int))
 *            <p>
 * @param parent
 *            The parent that this view will eventually be attached to.
 * @return the view that defines how this Buddy object is represented in the
 *         ListView / A View corresponding to the data at the specified
 *         position.
 * 
 * @see {@link BaseAdapter#getView(int, View, ViewGroup)}
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        // ROW INFLATION
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
    }

    // Get item
    Buddy buddy = getItem(position);
    buddy.refresh();

    buddyName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.buddy_name);   //change this to textField1  from simple_list_item_2
    buddyName.setText(buddy.toString());

    buddyStatus = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.buddy_mood); //change this to textField2 from simple_list_item_2
    buddyStatus.setText(buddy.getMood());
    //      Log.d(tag, buddy.getIdentity()+"'s mood is "+buddyStatus.getText());



    return row;
}
```

So i propose you expand the constructor with an additional ArrayList which contains the subtexts and then use em instead of the buddy.getMood() call.

Finally, instantiate this adapter and set it as the listView's adapter. Voila, you've got both texts showing up ;)

For further refinement, make your own XML file containing two textViews, like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.skype.widget.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/buddy_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:text="@string/buddy_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/buddy_mood"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empty_string"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-350dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|bottom"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

and instead of

```
  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
```

do

```
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddy_list_item, parent, false);
```

There you go, now you know how to make adapters work with custom XMLs and listViews.

Answer (score 2):

messages - is a `List<Map<String, String>>`,
title and data - is keys of map.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, messages,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[] {"title", "data"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
        android.R.id.text2,
    });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thats all you need.

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayAdapter only knows how to deal with one TextView per row.  If you want it to deal with more you need to deal with that yourself by subclassing ArrayAdapter and overriding the `getView()` method.

Depending on how you are creating your array, there may be another answer as well.

If the array is being created from a DB (you show a hard-coded string array, but that might just be for your example as far as I know) and you are not constrained to the array by some other factor, you might consider using a CursorAdapter as they are already set up to deal with multiple TextViews without having to subclass the adapter, and it would save you the processing power of turning DB data into an array.

Comment: no, why would you switch your whole data organization just for one damn text field?

Comment: I said if possible.  A lot of people (for some reason) take data from a DB and turn it into an array because they don't understand cursoradapters.  They waste processing power on something that doesn't need to be done.  I merely mentioned it if that was the case.  I see nothing in my answer worth a downvote, but oh well.

Comment: LOL, always were, I'm not terribly thin skinned, and my answer could (obviously) have been misinterpreted.

Comment: yea, once you elaborated on it (and added it to the answer) it made sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this also programmatically using a basic item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBasicItem"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBasicItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blockbreaker3"
        android:background="#b3b3b3"
         />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutInsideBasicItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#b3b3b3"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBasicItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Affronta livelli ancora più complessi che ti porteranno al di là di un semplice schermo pieno di mattoncini."
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewPlatformItem"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBasicItem"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:text="Platform: "
          android:textSize="8dp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:ems="10" />
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewTypeItem"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textViewPlatformItem"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:text="Genere: "
          android:textSize="8dp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:ems="10" />
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewDateItem"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTypeItem"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:text="Data di lancio: "
          android:textSize="8dp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:ems="10"
          android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
           />
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewPriceItem"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:text="Gratis    "
          android:gravity="right"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textColor="#0096ff"
          android:ems="10"
           />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

by adding this layer to a vertical linear layout in my main activity

```
...
<ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewStep1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewStep1"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="#e8e8e8"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/collector"
            ></LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
...
```

The code inside tha activity which adds the items modifying their content is:

```
public void listViewTailer(int rootId, int itemId){

        LinearLayout collector = (LinearLayout) findViewById(rootId);    
        LinearLayout inflatedView;


        for(int i = 0; i < listFeeder.size(); i++){


            inflatedView = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, itemId, null);
            TextView description = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.textViewBasicItem);
            description.setText(listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdDescription());
            TextView platform = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.textViewPlatformItem);
            platform.setText(platform.getText() + "" + listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdPlatform());
            TextView type = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.textViewTypeItem);
            type.setText(type.getText() + "" + listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdType());
            TextView date = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.textViewDateItem);
            date.setText(date.getText() + "" + listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdDateAvailability());
            TextView price = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.textViewPriceItem);
            price.setText(listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdPrice() + "    ");

            collector.addView(inflatedView);

          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(id.imageViewBasicItem);
          imageView.setImageResource(listFeeder.getGameList().get(i).getPrdImage());

        }

    }
```

where rootId is the collector layout and itemId is the basic item added to the vertical linear layout.

Hope this can help.