# Why does my listview only show 1 item of the ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview

I have looked and found people with similar problems such as this with their listviews, but their solutions do not apply to what I am trying to do.

I have a ListView, as seen here:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Following is the code that I've conjured up to attempt to add Bible Verses to the list view, for instance, one item is to say `Genesis 1:1`, and the next item is to say `Exodus 5:5`. Each of the verses are in the ArrayList `Verses`, but only the first item is being displayed in the ListView

```
public void addVerse(View v)
{
    String bookName = spinnerBooks().getSelectedItem().toString();
    int chapter = spinnerChapters().getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
    int verse = spinnerVerses().getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;

    Verse newVerse = new Verse(bookName, chapter, verse);
    Verses.add(newVerse);
    UpdateVerses();
}

public void UpdateVerses()
{
    ArrayList<String> VersesStr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Verse vObj: Verses)
    {
        String addedStuff = vObj.book.getName() + " " + vObj.Chapter + ":" + vObj.Verse;
        VersesStr.add(addedStuff);
        //System.out.println("Adding this: " + addedStuff);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterS = new ArrayAdapter<String>(x,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, VersesStr);
    for (Verse v : Verses)
    {
        System.out.println(v.book.getName() + " " + v.Chapter + ":" + v.Verse);
    }
    listViewVerses().setAdapter(adapterS);
}
private ListView listViewVerses() { return (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); }
```

I'm also not here to debate on religious stuff, so please don't comment about the Bible verses.

Comment: Your listview isn't displayed properly? You have wrap_content for width and height in your layout

Comment: @Yaroslav I don't understand how that would have an effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ListView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

and you can also try `adapterS.notifyDataSetChanged();` If you are updating it in real time !

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after thinking, I realized that it was adding the items to the list view, but it was scrollable xD, but even with this proposed layout width and height changed, the height of the ListView is still equivalent to 1 list item

Comment: update answer with complete layout file, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 <- notice the 1. One TextView is all you get. [What is difference between android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722885/what-is-difference-between-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1-and-android-r-lay) (I agree the list item is worded a bit poorly but they don't care lol)

BTW, 2 is the max and then you need to create a custom one. Android provided lists are very simple lists.

Additionally, you can cheat and use \n in the text to make it look like there are more, though they would register as the same position so if you need separate click listeners this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking this was a possibility, but then I thought, well the people who make android can't be that stupid!

Comment: Anyhow, I just changed it to a spinner to make things more simple. :/ oh well