# My ListView is not displayed properly - how to fix that?

Tags: android, listview, android-view

My problem is that my listview just displays rectangle boxes with no options visible but when i click any item it displays list's text
Below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

below is my java file:

```
package com.example.mypc.contextmenuapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    String []arr=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2
             ,android.R.id.text1,arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: peehu gandhi look at that picture closely you can see the list  , just change the text color and it will be visible

Answer (score 1):

Change the line :-

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2
         ,android.R.id.text1,arr);
```

to

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
         ,android.R.id.text1,arr);
```

Differnce is that `simple_list_item_1` has a single textview while the `simple_list_item_2` has two textviews inside a subclass of `RelativeLayout`.

Also the `arrayadapter` does not fill multiple textview instances . You need to override `getView()` for that.

[This answer will make it more clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722885/what-is-difference-between-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1-and-android-r-lay)

Note: - Since the `listView` is already `match_parent` both width and height , there should be no need for align with bottom or end or right.

Try without specifying the textview resource id like:-

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
         ,arr)
```

Since without it , it uses the default textview  for displaying each item. But if  you want you own textview , create a layout with textview as the root view and set it id as above and refer it in the constructor with the textview resouceId.

But in your case you do not need it , so try using without it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed but still its not visible

Comment: did u try removing the alignments attributes too?

Comment: try without the id for textview like this:- adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         arr);

Comment: both should work diferently though have tested it , it seems to be some other issue

Comment: give a try on some real device.

Answer (score 0):

In your image ,texts are very pallid. When you click one of them, the background of the item becomes dark and the white text appears.
On the other hand if you want items with one textview ,you should use `ArrayAdapter`, otherwise you must extend `ArrayAdapter` class. Here is an example:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView